# Selecting or deleting tags while editing question wrongly goes to tag page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

While editing a question's tags, I noticed the following new, strange behavior:

- Clicking on the (X) to delete a tag removes the tag, but immediately also follows the link to the tag page.
- Typing a tag then selecting from the suggestions list with the mouse adds the tag, but also immediately follows the link to the tag page.

What makes this worse, is hitting browser-back from the tag page brings me back to the question, *not in editing mode* - all edits are lost.

Note: This seems to only happen on SO (i.e. it does *not* happen here).

Comment: This happened to a few people yesterday, but forcing a hard refresh/clearing their cache fixed things. Give that a try and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Did not reproduce on trying it out. So try a hard refresh, as Tim Stone suggested.

Comment: @TimStone Yes that is most definitely the answer. Thanks. Can you post that below as the answer? There's bound to be someone else who would benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TimStone suggests:

> This happened to a few people yesterday, but forcing a hard refresh/clearing their cache fixed things. Give that a try and see if the problem persists?